# Google Sheets Script - Repeating Multiple Strings X Times in Multiple Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**How can I repeat 'SAT' 10 times in a row and then 'SUN' times in a row more efficiently?**

I know I could use copy/paste, click/drag, custom functions ([like this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42711/repeat-range-under-each-other-in-google-spreadsheets)) and combinations of built-in functions like TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(REPT(). Those are great if you don't have to use them often. However, with more than just 'SAT' and 'SUN' as values, that quickly becomes cumbersome.

I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48604626/google-sheet-script-repeat-multiple-values-x-times) a few days ago. Working off the solutions provided by [dev1998](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5137019/dev1998) and [Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368381/serge-insas), I created a working script below.

```js
function testAtA1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('TEST'));

  // start columns and rows
  var currentRow = 1;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var numRows = 1; // Change to match number of items listed for a given variable
  var numColumns = 1;
  var day1 = [
    ['SAT']
  ]
  var day2 = [
    ['SUN']
  ]
  Logger.log(day1);
  Logger.log(day2);

  var day1Length = day1.length;
  var day2Length = day2.length;
  Logger.log(day1Length);
  Logger.log(day2Length);

  var currentRow2 = currentRow + 10
  // ranges where values will be placed

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    var target1 = sheet.getRange(currentRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValues(day1);
    currentRow = currentRow + 1; // Change to match number of items listed for a given variable
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var target2 = sheet.getRange(currentRow2, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValues(day2);
    currentRow2 = currentRow2 + 1
  }
}
```

In addition to what I have above, I also tried

```js
var days = [['SAT'],['SUN']]
```

I was able to get that to alternate SAT and then SUN X times, but not get all SAT in a row and all SUN in a row. With the first snippet I provided I was able to separate them but, I'm curious to know if there is an easier/better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function testAtA1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));

  // start columns and rows
  var currentRow = 1;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var numRows = 10; // Change to match number of items listed for a given variable
  var numColumns = 1;
  var days = ['SAT','SUN','MON']
  for (d = 0;d < days.length ; d++) {
    var data = days[d]
    var target1 = sheet.getRange(currentRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValue(data);
    currentRow = currentRow+10
}
}
```

By adding another variable d and making a another loop with d 
lesser than days.length  , We have a desired solution.

Comment: That's it. Thanks so much! I'm not sure how much longer it would have taken for me to stumble across that solution, if at all. For a fifth day of attempting scripts, it may have taken a few more days haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(D1:D7&"",10),,9^99),""))))
```

D1:D7 will contain SAT through FRI

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the various built-in functions like ARRAYFORMULA, but that is new to me. 

Could you walk me through some parts?  For the query itself and the headers of the query what do those really mean? A blank query and 9^99

While I am specifically looking to use script, it's nice having that as an alternative.

Comment: I was aware of how the other things worked. I've used similar combinations of functions in other instances, but this (the QUERY headers in particular), was new to me. Thanks! I am still looking to see if anyone knows how to do this via script. For now, I'll leave this open. If it goes unanswered for a bit more, I'll mark this as answered and later rephrase to specifically use script as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to append the rows to the spreadsheet, this will do the trick:

```
function addText(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

  var satRow = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    satRow.push("SAT");
  }

  var sunRow = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    sunRow.push("SUN");
  }

  ss.appendRow(satRow);
  ss.appendRow(sunRow)
}
```

`appendRow()` takes a 1-dimensional array as an argument. So just build a 1D array and append it.

If you need to insert the rows at an arbitrary point, you're probably better off going with a custom function:

```
/**
 * Fills a range specified in rows and columns with the specified value
 *
 * @param {number} Number of rows to fill
 * @param {number} Number of columns to fill
 * @param {string} input The value to iterate.
 * @return An array containing the values
 * @customfunction
 */
function fillRange(rows,cols,str){

  var output = [[]];

  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++){
    output[0].push(str);
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < rows; i++){
    output.push(output[0]);
  }

  return output;

}
```

To use it, type in a cell `=fillRange(1,2,"SAT")` to fill 2 columns in one row with "SAT".

Comment: thanks! The former isn't really what I'm looking for. The latter works easily enough. The issue I have with functions is placing them in other locations in a single column. Let's say I wanted to put all the days in a week in a single column and list each day 10 times, i'd have to manually go through and put the function into each row. Then you run into the problems associated with locked and relative cells.

Answer (score 0):

again a more efficient solution using array and bulk read/write as recommended in [best practice...](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

```
function testAtA1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEST');

  // start columns and rows
  var currentRow = 1;
  var startColumn = 1;
  var numRows = 1; // Change to match number of items listed for a given variable
  var numColumns = 1;
  var day1 = 'SAT';
  var day2 = 'SUN';
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getMaxRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  var currentRow2 = currentRow + 10 ;// ranges where values will be placed

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    data[i][0] = day1;
    data[i+10][0] = day2;
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```